# React class based components: infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, components

I have a problem with updating state in component. I'm building a todo app with class based component. In this app I have a filter so you can choose to show completed task, uncompleted tasks or all tasks. So I have an array with todos. And then I created another array: filteredItems, where I filter the todos according to which option has been choosen.

I do this in componentDidUpdate but I always get an infinite loop. Thank you for help.

Here is the code:

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [], text: "", option: "all", filteredItems: [] };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    switch (this.state.option) {
      case "completed":
        const completedItems = this.state.items.filter(
          (item) => item.completed
        );
        this.setState(() => ({
          filteredItems: completedItems,
        }));
        break;
      case "uncompleted":
        const uncompletedItems = this.state.items.filter(
          (item) => item.completed === false
        );
        this.setState(() => ({
          filteredItems: uncompletedItems,
        }));
        break;
      default:
        this.setState(() => ({
          filteredItems: this.state.items,
        }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-container">
        <h3>TODO</h3>
        <TodoForm
          items={this.state.items}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          handleOption={this.handleOption}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
        <TodoList
          items={this.state.items}
          deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo}
          softDeleteTodo={this.softDeleteTodo}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.text.length) {
      return;
    }
    const newItem = {
      text: this.state.text,
      id: Date.now(),
      completed: false,
    };
    this.setState((state) => ({
      items: [...state.items, newItem],
      text: "",
    }));
  };

  //Function delete todo
  deleteTodo = (item) => {
    const updateItems = this.state.items.filter(
      (element) => element.id !== item.id
    );

    this.setState(() => ({
      items: updateItems,
    }));
  };

  //Function softdeleteTodo
  softDeleteTodo = (item) => {
    const completedItems = this.state.items.map((element) => {
      if (element.id === item.id) {
        return { ...element, completed: !element.completed };
      }
      return element;
    });

    this.setState(() => ({
      items: completedItems,
    }));
  };

  //Set state according to which option was selected
  handleOption = (event) => {
    this.setState({ option: event.target.value });
  };
}

export default TodoApp;
```

TodoForm component:

```
import TodoInput from "./TodoInput";

export default function TodoForm({
  items,
  handleChange,
  handleSubmit,
  value,
  handleOption,
}) {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="new-todo">What needs to be done?</label>
      <TodoInput id="new-todo" handleChange={handleChange} value={value} />

      <button>{`Add #${items.length + 1}`}</button>

      <select onChange={handleOption}>
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
        <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**
You update state in `componentDidUpdate()`.

Once state updated, it re-render TodoApp Component.
As TodoApp Component re-render, `componentDidUpdate()` run again and update the state.
*This cycle repeats itslef again and again and you get infinity loop.*

*First of all get rid of `componentDidUpdate()`.*

**Solution no.1**
**1.** Create a function in TodoApp componet which takes one argument and and update your state in TodoApp componet.
**2.** Now pass this function as a prop in your TodoForm comment.
**3.** Now you can access this function in your TodoForm Component as a prop and you have to attach `onClick()` event in your select element's option and pass its option value to function received from TodoApp as a prop and update your state in TodoApp componet.

**Solution no. 2**
Don't store your `option` state in your `this.state`. Instead you can store your `option` state in state management library like `redux` and you have to dispatch an action to change your state.
Which intern render your Component one time.
In your TodoForm Component's select element's option, you have to attach `onClick()` event and dispatch an action from it.

> **Here You can learn more**
> [Click Here to watch tutorial to learn `React & Redux` or if you want to learn only `redux` then follow tuturial from 34 to 43 by TheNetNinja](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ij8CfkAY2RAGb-tmkNwQHG)