# React JS: My view model is causing an endless loop of rendering

Tags: reactjs, mvvm, rendering, render, infinite-loop

I am new to React JS, coming from iOS and so trying to implement MVVM. Not sure it's the right choice, but that's not my question. I would like to understand how react works and what am I doing wrong. So here's my code:

```
const ViewContractViewModel = () => {
  console.log('creating view model');
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(false);

  async function componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    setisLoading(true);
    // assume fetchValueFromServer works properly
    setValue(await fetchValueFromServer());
    console.log('value fetched from server');
    setisLoading(false);
  }

  return { componentDidMount, value, isLoading };
};

export default function ViewContract() {
  const { componentDidMount, value, isLoading } = ViewContractViewModel();
  useEffect(() => {
    componentDidMount();
  }, [componentDidMount]);

  return (
    <div className='App-header'>
      {isLoading ? 'Loading' : value ? value : 'View Contract'}
    </div>
  );
}
```

So here's what I understand happens here: the component is mounted, so I call `componentDidMount` on the view model, which invokes `setIsLoading(true)`, which causes a re-render of the component, which leads to the view model to be re-initialised and we call `componentDidMount` and there's the loop.

How can I avoid this loop? What is the proper way of creating a view model? How can I have code executed once after the component was presented?

EDIT: to make my question more general, the way I implemented MVVM here means that any declaration of `useState` in the view model will trigger a loop every time we call the `setXXX` function, as the component will be re-rendered, the view model recreated and the useState re-declared.

Any example of how to do it right?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React class based components: infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65157193/react-class-based-components-infinite-loop)

Comment: Actually, it does not. I'll re-phrase my question so that it is more general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern for in React is to `use{NameOfController}` and have it completely self-contained. This way, you don't have to manually call `componentDidMount` and, instead, you can just handle the common UI states of "loading", "error", and "success" within your view.

Using your example above, you can write a reusable controller hook like so:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "../api";

export default function useViewContractViewModel() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const data = await api.fetchValueFromServer();
        setData(data);
      } catch (error: any) {
        setError(error.toString());
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return { data, error, isLoading };
}
```

Then use it within your view component:

```
import useViewContractViewModel from "./hooks/useViewContractViewModel";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useViewContractViewModel();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : error ? (
        <p>Error: {error}</p>
      ) : (
        <p>{data || "View Contract"}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a demo:

[image: Edit Reusable Hook Example]

---

On a side note, if you want your controller hook to be more dynamic and can control the initial data set, then you can pass it props, which would then be added to the `useEffect` dependency array:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "../api";

export default function useViewContractViewModel(id?: number) {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const data = await api.fetchValueFromServer(id);
        setData(data);
      } catch (error: any) {
        setError(error.toString());
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    })();
  }, [id]);

  return { data, error, isLoading };
}
```

Or, you return a reusable callback function that allows you to refetch data within your view component:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "../api";

export default function useViewContractViewModel() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const fetchDataById = useCallback(async (id?: number) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setData("");
    setError("");

    try {
      const data = await api.fetchValueFromServer(id);
      setData(data);
    } catch (error: any) {
      setError(error.toString());
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
   fetchDataById()
  }, [fetchDataById]);

  return { data, error, fetchDataById, isLoading };
}
```